# Shortcode Wordpress para inserir layouts

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, shortcode

Estou criando um template Wordpress para um cliente, e preciso inserir layouts nas páginas, então criei o seguinte shortcode no `functions.php` do template:

```
<?php

function shortcode_add_layout( $atts , $content = null ) {
   extract(
      shortcode_atts(
         array(
            'add' => 'home',
         ),
         $atts
      )
   );

   $file = get_template_directory_uri() . '/layouts/' . $add . '.php';

   if (!file_exists($file)) {
      echo file_get_contents($file);
   } else {
      echo 'Oops, layout not found';
   }
}

add_shortcode('layout', 'shortcode_add_layout');

# [layout add='home']

?>
```

Com isso, coloco os arquivos com os layouts na pasta '/layouts', dentro da pasta do template, e ao chamar o shortcode, exibe o conteúdo do arquivo.

Essa foi a solução que encontrei, pois nenhum tipo de código com includes funcionou, entretanto esta demorando demais para carregar,o que posso fazer para deixa-lo mais rápido, como fosse um `include` comum?

Comment: Veja se essa [resposta](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/49715/125220) na comunidade [WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) possa te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) para dar o include usando a API do WordPress. É mais simples, falha sileciosamente (não dá erro se o arquivo não existir) e ainda permite o acesso aos filtros de manipulação de templates:

```
<?php

function shortcode_add_layout( $atts , $content = null ) {
   extract(
      shortcode_atts(
         array(
            'add' => 'home',
         ),
         $atts
      )
   );

   get_template_part( 'layouts/' . $add );
}

add_shortcode('layout', 'shortcode_add_layout');

# [layout add='home']

?>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente!